# foursquare venue categories api update

Tags: api, foursquare

It looks like the API response for venue categories has changed recently: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/categories

The "icon" field now only returns "prefix" and "suffix", instead of "prefix", "sizes" and "name".  To get the category icon to load, you have to concatenate prefix + "bg_32" + suffix, replacing 32 with whatever size you want: 32, 44, 64, 88, 256.

Comment: API version 20120609 and higher contain a number of breaking changes related to the foursquare 5.0 release. We'll be documenting the changes over the coming weeks. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/foursquare-api/MpNpdO5zARU for details.